# What is the best way to export an artwork in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, images, png, illustrator-scripting

I have 18 artworks in an .eps file.

[image]

I wonder what is the best way to extract/export one of those artwork into a .png/.jpg ?

Example

[image]

I'm not sure if this possible, but is there a way to export all of them into individual .png files.

Any helps / suggestions  on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need to select all your artworks, then go Object>Slice>Make
2. file> save for web, after choosing the slice select tool from the left panel you can select each artwork holding shift, and then change from the right panel the options (file type, quality etc.)
3. you can use slice select tool by double clicking on each object, it will bring a dialog box where you can input in Name field a name of the specific artwork. (each artwork file will have specific name which was inputed)
4. to export your artworks (slices) you need to change from the right panel on the bottom Export: All user slices. Press save btn

Comment: I'm getting close at least. I got 286 items exported, and I only want 18 of them.

Comment: Might want to mention that you need to group each illustration into it's own group before slicing.
This is better than my answer. It's worth noting that the slices won't size correctly if clipping masks are involved, but that isn't likely to be an issue in this case.

Comment: Ok then for the 1st point instead of all you need to select 18 artworks holding shift key, and then the same steps.

Comment: select 1 at a time ? I'm entirely sure.

Comment: Now, I got them, I kind of select each one manually, and hit `cmd + G` on 18 of them, then slice them and save them. But I still get 304 objects exported. ???

Comment: Yes selecting one at a time holding shift key, as wing-it mentioned your artworks (i.e. cactus in pot) should be grouped.

Comment: Cool. will do . Thanks for you help. What is shift key do - when selecting ? Also, why do I still get so many pieces exported. How can I stop that ?

Comment: a) when you do 1st point make sure that you have been selected only 18 artworks, b) that on point 4 you changed "Export" option to "All user slices"

Comment: If the picture above is everything in your file, and each illustration is it's own group, you shouldn't be getting so many pieces. It's hard to help you specifically without knowing exactly what the contents of the file are.

Comment: SHIFT -> Multiselection

Comment: @twinklingstar : I got all 18 of them exported it now, I'm so happy. You both make my day as you can see I'm not a designer. I know nothing about Illustrator. Thank again for both of your help. You guys are awesome.

Comment: One last question, you guys know my filename index is not consistent ? I see _03.png, 05, 32, 58, 63, so on and so forth ... Shouldn't it be 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 18

Comment: after you do the 1st step, you should notice that the artwork has bounding box with the small number on it , on the top corner. This numbers implement in the file name. If you want to have i.e a, b,c, instead of generated names, you can do that as described in the 3rd point.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your enthusiasm for helps on this post.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I know to do this is to create a separate artboard for each illustration. To do this, make sure each one is grouped together.

Go to **File->Document Setup->Edit Artboards** or just hit **Shift+o** to start editing the artboards. Then just click twice (not double-click) on each group to make a new artboard for each one, it will automatically size each artboard to the art. You'll probably want to delete your original artboard. If it's important that you save your original artboard, you may want to save the file as a copy of your original.

Then simply select **File->Export**, select **PNG** as your file time, check the box next to **Use Artboards** and make sure **All** is selected under that. When you hit **Export** it will bring up a dialog box that will let you select resolution, anti-aliasing and backgroundcolor options. When you hit **OK** it will output each artboard as separate files into your chosen directory, with the artboard number as a suffix for each one.

I'm sure there is a way to write a script to make the artboards for you, but unless you have many files like this it will only take a minute to set up the artboards, so it's probably not necessary unless you foresee doing this operation a lot.